# Jupyter notebook: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I had issue with scipy package and not sure how to resolve it. Below is my module calling. No matter how I installed and uninstalled scipy, it kept saying there's no module named scipy.

```
#export
import csv
import numpy as np  # http://www.numpy.org
import ast
from datetime import datetime
from math import log, floor, ceil
import random
import numpy as np
!pip install -U scipy
import scipy
from scipy import stats
```

Here is the error message I got.

```
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /Users/suya/opt/anaconda3/envs/AnacondaEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.7.1)
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.7.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (33.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 33.0 MB 10.0 MB/s eta 0:00:01
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5 in /Users/suya/opt/anaconda3/envs/AnacondaEnv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scipy) (1.21.2)
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.7.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.7.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.7.1
Successfully installed scipy-1.7.2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/_n/9843mvyj5kj4z5z6m261thl80000gn/T/ipykernel_44142/3483349815.py in <module>
      8 import numpy as np
      9 get_ipython().system('pip install -U scipy')
---> 10 import scipy
     11 from scipy import stats

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Comment: I have faced a similar issue. I am not sure if this resolves your problem, but it fixed my issue with pandas.
Check out your site-package folder and see if a folder call "~cipy" is present in it. 
If so, remove it and reinstall the Scipy package

Comment: After installing packages you always need to restart the kernel so that Python can pick them up. So what you're trying to do (install Scipy and start using it in the same cell) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use differnt kernal(python), you install scipy on differnt python from  your jupyter notebook python(kernel)

you can install package inside of your jupyter notebook

```
!pip install scipy
```

Comment: For some reason still not working for me. It's saying Requirement already satisfied: numpy. But then saying no module.

Comment: Getting the same issue! Unable to use scipy inside Jupyter notebook even after installing scipy in the notebook.